# How to Rerun a function that will switch variables in a dictionary and run its self again?

Tags: ios, swift

Hey i have 2 simple dictionary's of a string and number. I want to be able to once ran the function be able to run it again but this time for barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals2 instead of the originally one. so the function basically runs it for the first one then changes the var goalCount to the second dictionary name and runs it's self again automatically. It seem simple Any Help. Thanks!
Code:

```
var barcelonavsRealMadrid1 = [barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals, barcelonavsRealMadrid1penaltys]

var barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals : [String : Int] = ["barcelonaGoal0":14,"RealMadridGoal1":12,"barcelonaGoal2":29,"RealMadridGoal3":30]

var barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals2 : [String : Int] = ["barcelonaGoal0":14,"RealMadridGoal1":12,"barcelonaGoal2":29,"RealMadridGoal3":30]

func run() {

        var goalCount = barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals.reduce(0, combine: {
            (initial:Int, current:(key:String, value:Int)) -> Int in
            var currentCount = initial
            print("\(current.key)\", \((current.value))", terminator:", ")

            defer {

            }
            if current.value <= 30 {
                ++currentCount // add 1 to the running total
                return currentCount
            }

            return currentCount
           // This is where i want to rerun the function but with the second dictionary now
           goalCount = barcelonavsRealMadrid1(index + 1) 
        })
```

like have barcelonavsRealMadrid1 first index slot run then have its second one run when the func finish the first one so basically changing the var goal count and then start again

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the variable as a parameter to the function and base it off of that.

For example (FYI Not Tested):

```
var barcelonavsRealMadrid1 = [barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals, barcelonavsRealMadrid1penaltys]
var barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals : [String : Int] = ["barcelonaGoal0":14,"RealMadridGoal1":12,"barcelonaGoal2":29,"RealMadridGoal3":30]
var barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals2 : [String : Int] = ["barcelonaGoal0":14,"RealMadridGoal1":12,"barcelonaGoal2":29,"RealMadridGoal3":30]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    run()
}

func run(goal:[String : Int]?) {
    if let _goal = goal {
        var goalCount = _goal.reduce(0, combine: {
            (initial:Int, current:(key:String, value:Int)) -> Int in
            var currentCount = initial;
            print("KEY: \(current.key) VALUE: \(current.value)")

            if current.value <= 30 {
                ++currentCount // add 1 to the running total
                return currentCount
            }

            return currentCount
        })
    } else {
        var goalCount = barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals.reduce(0, combine: {
            (initial:Int, current:(key:String, value:Int)) -> Int in
            var currentCount = initial;
            print("KEY: \(current.key) VALUE: \(current.value)")

            if current.value <= 30 {
                ++currentCount // add 1 to the running total
                return currentCount
            }

            run(barcelonavsRealMadrid1goals2)
            return currentCount
        })
    }
}
```